# How can I see the line spacing between lines?

Tags: fonts, spacing, fontsize, line-spacing, font-encodings

I have this command:

```latex
\newcommand{\showfont}
{%
    (\foreignlanguage{english}
    {%
        encoding: \f@encoding{},
        family: \f@family{},
        series: \f@series{},
        shape: \f@shape{},
        size: \f@size{},
        baseline: \f@baselineskip{}
    })
}
```

Which shows me details about my font on the current line. For example: `(encoding: T1, family: cmr, series: m, shape: n, size: 12, baseline: 18.0pt )`

How can I also put it to show the spacing between lines, i.e.: `(linespacing: 15pt, encoding: T1, family: cmr, series: m, shape: n, size: 12, baseline: 18.0pt )`

[image]

For example, supposing I am suing `memoir` and had set `\OnehalfSpacing`, it should show I have `(linespacing: 15pt, ...)`:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\OnehalfSpacing

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showfont}
{%
    (\foreignlanguage{english}
    {%
        encoding: \f@encoding{},
        family: \f@family{},
        series: \f@series{},
        shape: \f@shape{},
        size: \f@size{},
        baseline: \f@baselineskip{}
    })
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
versions of Lorem Ipsum \showfont.
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is baselineskip, which you are showing already (might be better to show `\baselineskip` rather than `\f@baselineskip`) . why do you think the spacing should be 1.5cm ???

Comment: As David said, the actual value is stored in `\baselineskip` (which is what TeX uses to compute the line spacing). If you want to use LaTeX's parameters you need the product `\f@linespread*\f@baselineskip`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I though the distance were `1.5cm`.

Comment: have you ever seen lines typeset 1.5cm apart??? a typical 10pt font is on 12pt baseline. 12pt is just over 4mm not 15mm.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I cannot say I see how many `cm` a font has just by looking at a PDF document, so I have to guess something.

Comment: If my font has 12pt, and I use `\OnehalfSpacing` latex shows `\baselineskip` as `15pt`. But a `\OnehalfSpacing` should not be `18pt`, i.e., 12pt / 2 = 6pt, then, `12pt + 6pt = 18pt`?

Comment: but a centimetre is just a standard unit of measurement if you look at two lines of text surely it is clear they are much less than a centimetre apart? It doesn't matter it just seemed a strange sort of guess:-)

Comment: @user no. double spacing does not mean double `\baselineskip` and onehalf spacing does not mean multiply it by 1.5

Comment: the numbers are not exact but for example the `setspace` package multiplies the baselineskip by 1.25 for onehalf spacing and 1.667 for double spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comments, I build the command like this:

```latex
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\OnehalfSpacing

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showfont}
{%
    (\foreignlanguage{english}
    {%
        encoding: \f@encoding{},
        family: \f@family{},
        series: \f@series{},
        shape: \f@shape{},
        size: \f@size{},
        baseline: \f@baselineskip{},
        linespread: \f@linespread{},
        linespacing: \the\baselineskip{}%
    })%
}
\makeatother
```